# Как считать из файла?

Tags: java

Мне нужно считать данные с текстового файла. Текст еще нужно будет распарсить. В Файле храняться строчки вот такого вида:

```
1000016501338441943     age=48  age_segment=4   income_segment=2    sex=1   sex_segment=0   yauid=1000016501338441943   gender_aff=0.19773578803522018;0.8022642119647799   age_aff=0.014156633559363991;0.18855573434316739;0.36762286444516556;0.26416482954032255;0.1654999381119805 income_aff=0.003793159731392532;0.48798171689209974;0.5082251233765076
```

Это содержание ОДНОЙ СТРОЧКИ.
Как мне достать отсюда лишь только числа, что идут после "=" и как достать группы чисел, идущих через точку с запятой, например отсюда - "0.19773578803522018;0.8022642119647799"

Как работать с разделителями табуляция, пробел?

Comment: См. метод .split(String regex) у String. Т.е. для пробелов `s.split("\\s+")`, для = -- `s.split("=")` и т.д.

Comment: регулярками же)

Comment: А нельзя как-нибудь сразу распарсить, а не в несколько подходов?

Comment: Можно. Но не уверен, что это будет проще.

Comment: Да?
Просто видел пример, там вроде все просто было.. только потерял его(

А как будет выглядеть в этом случае?

Comment: Ну можно, например, взять и почитать доки по javacc. Но если проблема только в нескольких проходах, то можно разбить строку одним spllit'ом:

    String a[] = s.split("\\s|=|;");

Только что потом с этим массивом делать?

Comment: Вообщем-то, мне с этим массивом нужно будет дальше работать.
Было бы неплохо из него вообще убрать все, кроме чисел..

Comment: @StasOn

    Было бы неплохо из него вообще убрать все, кроме чисел..

Вы это серьёзно? А как Вы будете в этом массиве ориентироваться. Я не знаю, известна ли заранее длина списков чисел (которые через ;), но даже если так, то оно может в любой момент измениться. И что тогда с массивом чисел. Скорее всего какая-то структура (дерево, типа DOM и т.д.), где можно делать осмысленную навигацию.

Comment: У меня файл состоит из нескольких таких вот строчек. мне нужно из каждой строчки взять по определенному числу и проинициализировать несколько объектов класса.

Считав каждую строчку в отдельности буду ее парсить и доставать все необходимое.

Структура строк одна и та же на весь файл

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так:

```
class A {
  public static void main (String args []) {
    String s = "1000016501338441943     age=48  age_segment=4   income_segment=2    sex=1   sex_segment=0   yauid=1000016501338441943   gender_aff=0.19773578803522018;0.8022642119647799";
    String a1[] = s.split("\\s+");
    String a2[] = a1[7].split("=");
    String a3[] = a2[1].split(";");
    System.out.println(a1[0]);
    System.out.println(a2[0]);
    System.out.println(a3[0]);
  }
```

}

Исходная строка сокращена -- в комментарий не влезает